# ItemsControl set DataContext to Item in a Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create kind of a gantt-chart planning tool. The first column should display the data of each planning-step. The second column should host a canvas where a textbox is displayed, whereas the Left and Width Values are derived from the data. This works ok, but the canvas always shows textboxes all items of the Planings collection, instead of the one according to the row of the record.

I'm pretty sure that this line is the problem:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Planings, ElementName=dgPlanings}" >
```

as it references the whole collection instead of record.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPlanings" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Planings}" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Baustellenspalte-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="Nr" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Text="To" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Text="Till" Grid.Column="2"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox Text="&#xE77B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Grid.Column="3"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox ></TextBox>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding To, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1"></DatePicker>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Till, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2"></DatePicker>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Workers}" Grid.Column="3"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!--Planungsspalte-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Planings, ElementName=dgPlanings}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}">
                                            <Binding Path="To" Mode="OneWay"  diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
                                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Right">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}">
                                            <Binding Path="Till" Mode="OneWay" />
                                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=coPlanung}" Background="White" Height="30" Margin="0"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=To }"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

What do I have to set the DataContext of the itemssource to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using an `ItemsControl` if you only want to display a single `TextBox` for each row? This doesn't make much sense. The `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` can only be set or bound to an `IEnumerable`.

You should put the `Canvas` and the `TextBox` directly into the DataTemplate:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=coPlanung}" Background="White" Height="30" Margin="0">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=To}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}">
                                        <Binding Path="To" Mode="OneWay" diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Right">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource d2x}">
                                        <Binding Path="Till" Mode="OneWay" />
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="coPlanung" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Of Course! Thanks. I want to show all bars in the columnheader, which works fine with the itempresenter... some days you just get stuck.